# Are XSD always generated using third-party tools?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd.exe, dtd

I am a beginner with XML. I can do `DTD` fairly well.

While learning about `XSD` and how to generate it, I found that all the tutorials available on Google and those on YouTube create `XSD` using third-party tools. For Windows they use either `VB` or `xsd.exe` tool.

Although handy, from a learner's point-of-view they are not good as I should know how to do it manually and later move on to automated schema generation.

My question is:

Are `XSD`s and `DTD`s always generated using third party tools ?

If they are handwritten, where can I find a good source of knowledge for it?

*I am on a Windows machine, by the way :)*

Comment: Hi, 

no you can write your own xsd-files and test them.Do you want something like extract xsd from xml?

Comment: @tingel2k No, I just want to create a schema for an existing XML document as practice. That's it. I made a DTD now I was moving to XSD. If that is what 'extraction' means :)

Comment: To try out your hand-crafted XSD and DTD, I recommend XML Nanny. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xml-nanny/id423791387

Comment: XSD is XML file. You can create it by own but if you are tring to create XSD from XML file, it needs some tools. For more details on XSD follow http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/index.htm link

Comment: You can write it by hand and test it against your file with http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html xmllint

Comment: @tingel2k That all answers  my first question :) but what about the second one? :)

Comment: take a look here http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/ and here http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/ but they are the full documentation/specification. But I think the best is here http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp

Comment: @tingel2k if you can put all what you said in the comments as an answer then I will accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You can write it by hand and test it against your file with [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)

2: Take a look here [w3c doc-1](http://w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1) and here [w3c doc-2](http://w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2) but they are the full documentation/specification. 
But I think the best is here [xsd-tutorial](http://w3schools.com/schema/default.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Writing a schema without any tools assistance at all is a bit masochistic. If you know the language reasonably well, a syntax-directed editor (such as oXygen) might be enough tooling for your needs. However, if you've got an instance document available that's reasonably representative of what you will encounter, then generating an XSD from the instance and modifying the generated XSD as required will save you a lot of effort.

You definitely need a reference book on your desk. I use both van der Vlist and Walmsley.

Comment: You see, sir, people here abhor asking for reference to literature in the strongest possible ways. I do not know why but as far as I can remember books are the best source of knowledge.

Comment: Hey can you help me with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471559/how-do-i-add-namespaces-to-an-xsd

Answer (score 1):

I have written several by myself (with the assistance of some documentation) [this link](http://www.codalogic.com/lmx/xsd-overview.html) I actually prefer to do it myself, because the automatic ones may not work like I'd like them to (using Choices instead of sequences for example)